# login failed using google ID

Tags: support, login, linked-accounts

I have always been logging in stackoverflow using my google id. My google id was actually my hotmail id. it has something to do with google all acounts with one ID thing, not really sure how it works. but apparently your multiple Accounts can be associated under one google account.

Just another day when I was logging on my google account it gave me an option of creating a gmail account. fair enough I created that account. and it assigned me some blabla@gmail.com account.

Now when I tried to log on stackoverflow with that gmail ID which is basically is the same account All accounts under one google Account thing. Stackoverflow created a new account for me.

Now I cannot log in to my SO account using my google ID anymore it takes me to this new account. And if I try to login using my hotmail account it doesnt accept it. Now I am using my facebook ID to login.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can login to SO using my google ID again please?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to merge your accounts, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for more details.